# How can I set random positions on radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this script I'm creating a circle with specific radius size and get the radius size :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawRadiusAroundTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5f)]
    public float width = 0.1f;
    LineRenderer line;

    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.enabled = true;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        CreatePoints();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CreatePoints();
    }

    public Vector3[] CreatePoints()
    {
        line.widthMultiplier = width;

        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        float angle = 20f;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0f, y));

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        var positions = new Vector3[line.positionCount];

        return positions;
    }
}
```

And in this script I have this method and I want the last point/s to be set randomly on the radius edge positions :

```
private void GeneratePointsInTracks()
    {
        var startPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Start Point");
        var curvedLines = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line");

        for (int i = 0; i < startPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPointsInTrack; x++)
            {
                GameObject go = Instantiate(tracksPrefab, curvedLines[i].transform);
                go.name = "Point In Track";
                go.transform.position = turrent.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f));

                if(x == numberOfPointsInTrack - 1)
                {
                    go.name = "Last Point In Track";

                    for(int y = 0; y < drawRadius.CreatePoints().Length; y++)
                    {
                        go.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0,1)[y].x,
                            drawRadius.CreatePoints()[y].y,
                            drawRadius.CreatePoints()[y].z);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this :

```
 go.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0,1)[y].x,
                                drawRadius.CreatePoints()[y].y,
                                drawRadius.CreatePoints()[y].z);
```

but the random on the x give error :

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

The first script create a circle like this :

[image: Circle]

And this is an example I drawed in paint just to show what I mean that I said I want the endPoints in the second script to be position randomly on the circle edges :

[image: Example]

So each "Last Point In Track" object should be position randomly on the circle edge like in the second screenshot.

Comment: `Random.Range(0,1)` is just a number, not a collection, don't try to access it with an index `y`

Comment: Also in the end of the first snippet you do `var positions = new Vector3[line.positionCount]; return positions;` so you always return an array with zero vectors, which is not what you want

Comment: Do you want to pick random positions from the ones you already set in the LineRenderer, or just random positions on the circle?

Comment: @Pluto I want that the endPoint in the second script each endPoint to be positioned on a random position on the circle from the first script.

Comment: @Pluto I updated my question with two screenshots at the bottom explain what I mean.

Comment: @AlexLarionov Right, Then how can I get the positions of the circle edges points each time I change the radius ? Where should I make the instance of the var positions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the center and radius it is fairly easy to get random points on the circle:

```
go.name = "Last Point In Track";
Vector2 p = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * radius;
go.transform.position = center + new Vector3(p.x, 0, p.y);
```

To get rid of the edge case where Random.insideUnitCircle is to small to be normalized you should use:

```
Vector2 RandomOnUnitCircle(){
    Vector2 result = Vector2.zero;
    do{
        result = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized;
    }while(result == Vector2.zero);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How can I return or get from the first script CreatePoints the circle radius and center ?

Comment: In the second script at the top I added public DrawRadiusAroundTurret drawRadius; so I will be able to access the CreatePoints method from the first script but I'm not sure how to get both the radius and center.

Comment: Radius should be `drawRadius.xradius` and center `drawRadius.transform.position` if you have the circle around the gameobject that has the `DrawRadiusAroundTurret` script attached.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
Vector3[] points = drawRadius.CreatePoints(); //get all edge points
Vector3 randomPoint = points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)]; //pick a random one

go.transform.position = randomPoint; //set go.transform.position to position of random point
```

Sorry if I am misunderstanding your intentions, but I hope this works for you!